# Can I create dynamic temporary table using iBatis?

Tags: java, mysql, ibatis

During a query of a user's contacts, I want to use a temporary table specific to that user, e.g. tmp_contact_{userId}, if userId is 123, should resolve to tmp_contact_123

I have inherited a java project that uses iBatis to interoperate with a MySql database.
I've read some of the iBatis documentation, and I see replaceable parameters in the xml as either #{userId} or #userId#. The former appears to be interpreted as a parameter for a prepared statement and produces a question mark, e.g. 'create temporary table tmp_contact_?', while the latter was left as a literal, e.g. 'create temporary table tmp_contact_#userId#'.
Is there alternate syntax to produce 'create temporary table tmp_contact_123'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do this!

Using `#` puts a quote around string params. You can use `$` instead. For your example, it would be

```
create temporary table tmp_contact_$userId$
```

When iBatis compiles this statement it will be

```
create temporary table tmp_contact_123
```

and not

```
create temporary table tmp_contact_'123'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do following changes in your .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<sqlMap namespace="xxx" xmlns="http://ibatis.apache.org/mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <statements>
    <select id="GetTempTableData" resultClass="Student" parameterClass="System.String">
        CREATE TABLE ##TEMPTABLE (ID int, Name varchar(20))
        INSERT INTO ##TEMPTABLE (ID, NAME) VALUES (1, 'RAVI')
        INSERT INTO ##TEMPTABLE (ID, NAME) VALUES (2, 'KAPIL')
        SELECT * FROM ##TEMPTABLE
    </select>   
  </statements>
</sqlMap>
```

Note : You need to create temp table inside the select satement. You need to use double "##" to create temp table in IBATIS. "##" will replaced with single "#" and it will create temp table with the name of "#TEMPTABLE". Please remember their are some limitation of temp table that you need to search.

Hope this will help you..